# Match a field property containing $ in the name

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I saved a lot of aggregations pipeline into a collection :

```
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56d06614070b7f2b117b23db"),
        "ops" : [
            {
                "$unwind" : "$x"
            },
            {
                "$unwind" : "$y"
            },
            {
                "$match" : {
                    "brand" : "z"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to make some statistics on those data :

```
db.apicalls.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$ops"},{"$match":{***...***}}])
```

The result from the unwind operation alone is like this :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d06631070b7f11117b23d4"), "ops" : { "$match" : { "brand" : "zzz" } } },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d06631070b7f11117b23d4"), "ops" : { "$unwind" : "$x" } }
```

I want to be able to match only the $match operations saved into the collection. 
Someone haves how to select on the key "$match" ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want a match stage that can match the string `$match`?

Comment: Exactly. My first problem is to match on a subdocument's key. the second one is to do that on "$match" which creates an error

Comment: You should not have even been allowed to save data with fields prefixed with `$`. How did you actually do that? My guess would be that you **actually** have an escaped string like `\$match` and therefore your question is a bit misleading.

Comment: It's the PHP driver who escaped the $. How can I do to match \$match if works ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is misleading. Since the `$` characters are "illegal" as the property names in a MongoDB document, they actually would be "escaped" with a "slash" `\`:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d06614070b7f2b117b23db"),
    "ops" : [
        {
            "\$unwind" : "$x"
        },
        {
            "\$unwind" : "$y"
        },
        {
            "\$match" : {
                    "brand" : "z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Therefore you would need to include all characters in the key to look for using the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator to find `\$match`:

```js
db.apicalls.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$ops" },
  { "$match": {
    "ops.\\$match": { "$exists": true }
  }}
])
```

Which returns the correct document:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d06614070b7f2b117b23db"), "ops" : { "\$match" : { "brand" : "z" } } }
```